# How can I take substring in Oracle

Tags: oracle, substring

I have a row string  in oracle table.

`Some text № 3694452 from 31.08.2013, stilltext 02.09.2013 18:16:27`

How can I take  "02.09.2013 18:16:27" (from the end of row and after stilltext)
for converting it to date.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Because it's good practice to.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the date string always positioned at the end of text,
you can use regular expression like this:

```
select
  to_date(
    regexp_substr(your_column_name, '\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$'),
    'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
from you_table_name;
```

Comment: Lot of Thanks. All what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the date is always at the end of the string and is fixed in format.

```
with dummy as 
  (select '3694452 from 31.08.2013, stilltext 02.09.2013 18:16:27' data
   from dual)
select to_date(substr(data,length(data)-19), 'MM.DD.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
from dummy
```

There are more elegant ways to do this with regular expressions, but I am assuming this will suffice.

[SQL Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/462dc4/7)

Comment: Thanks so much,I think it what me need.  In expression I have problem - how grab text in end of row. I can write expression for validate but  can't write in this case. But I will try find in that approach too. Thanks you soo much.

Comment: btw `length(data)-19` in this case can be shortened to just `-19`.